# Creating a TFS workspace - MinGW compatibility issue

Tags: tfs, mingw, workspace

I'm trying to create a TFS workspace using the **tf** command.

It works perfectly from Windows command prompt:

```
C:\Tmp> "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" workspace /new TemporaryWorkspace /s:http://srv:8080/tfs /noprompt
```

Exactly the same command fails when executed from a MinGW (msys) window (MinGW 3.18 under Windows XP SP2):

```
$ "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/TF.exe" workspace /new TemporaryWorkspace /s:http://srv:8080/tfs /noprompt
Specify one workspace.
```

Other TFS commands (such as **get**, **workspaces** etc.) work correctly under MinGW.

Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you use the /collection argument instead of /s ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the shell you are using is parsing /n as a newline so not passing the option along correctly to tf.exe.  However because of this issue tf actually accepts a hypden (-) instead of slash (/) for all options.  So try something like:

```
$ "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/TF.exe" workspace 
      -new TemporaryWorkspace 
      -collection:http://srv:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection 
      -noprompt
```

If you are doing this programmatically you might also need `-login:username@domain:password`